# CSS overflow rule includes object border?

Tags: html, css

Say I have a "div" element with a border assigned to it. If the overflow rule for it is set to 'hidden', content that is ON the border of the "div" disappears.

Is there any way to overcome this? Because in my scenario, having content that is on the border not disappear is very important. I need the boundaries of my element to include the border too.

Comment: No, you need to change the HTML. You could create a div that has the border you want to show and create another div inside it that has content that overflows on the borders.

Comment: That was my idea too, but it would be too cumbersome in my case since the scripting relies heavily on the current DOM structure. Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: You should be able to easily remove the border of the container that's scripted and create a static div with the border you want. That way, you wouldn't have to change the script. I imagine that your content is appended to the DOM dynamically.

Comment: That's right, it's appended dynamically. I'll see what I can do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to find out what doesn't work to get to the working solution. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it will take three `div's` to achieve this (maybe somebody can come up with a two `div` solution). Here is [an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JxmH/4/). Three nested `div` elements (the outer here has the `.CropIt` class) with:

**CSS**

```
.CropIt {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 60px;
}

.CropIt > div {
    border: 20px solid red;
    width: 20px;
}

.CropIt > div > div {
    margin: -20px;
}
```

The outer sets the overflow to hide past the border hidden. The middle sets the width and border (which outer must match that total width *or* use `float` to shrink wrap). The innermost set's the negative margin to push the content over the border of middle, and create the overlap of the border to the middle `div`.